# Approach to this integral

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, special-functions, hermite-polynomials

According to a standard literature

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}q}\int^{-d}_{−∞}  \sum ^∞_{k=1} \frac{(A^2/2q^2)^k}{2^k(k!^2)} e^\frac{−r^2}{2q^2}He_{2k}(\frac{r}{q})dr=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \sum ^∞_{k=1} \frac{(A^2/2q^2)^k}{2^k(k!^2)} e^\frac{−d^2}{2q^2}He_{2k}(\frac{d}{q})$$where $$He_n(x)$$ & $$H_n(x)$$is the Hermite Polynomial probabilist's and physicist's convention. My approach is like this:

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}q}\int^{-d}_{−\infty}  \sum ^\infty_{k=1} \frac{(A^2/2q^2)^k}{2^k(k!^2)} e^{−r^2/2q^2}He_{2k}(r/q)dr=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}q}\sum ^\infty_{k=1} \frac{(A^2/2q^2)^k}{2^k(k!^2)}[\int^{0}_{−\infty}   e^\frac{−r^2}{2q^2}He_{2k}(\frac{r}{q})dr+\int^{-d}_{0}   e^\frac{−r^2}{2q^2}He_{2k}(\frac{r}{q})dr] \tag{1}$$
Converting Hermite Polynomial probabilist's convention to physicist's  convention.
$$\int^{-d}_{0}   e^\frac{−r^2}{2q^2}He_{2k}(\frac{r}{q})dr=\int^{-d}_{0}   2^{-k}e^\frac{−r^2}{2q^2}H_{2k}(\frac{r}{\sqrt{2}q})dr$$

let $$ t=\frac{r}{\sqrt{2}q} $$ then changing integration variable and limits we get
$$\int^{-d}_{0}   2^{-k}e^\frac{−r^2}{2q^2}H_{2k}(\frac{r}{\sqrt{2}q})dr=2^{-k}\sqrt{2}q\int^{\frac{-d}{\sqrt{2}q}}_{0}   e^{-t^2}H_{2k}(t)dt=2^{-k}\sqrt{2}q[H_{2k-1}(0)- e^{-d^2/2q^2}H_{2k-1}(-d/\sqrt{2}q)]=2^{-k}\sqrt{2}q e^{-d^2/2q^2}H_{2k-1}(d/\sqrt{2}q)  $$

$$H_{2n-1}(0)=0 \qquad\text{and}\qquad H_{n}(-x)=(-1)^nH_{n}(x)$$

Going back to the probabilist's form
$$2^{-k}\sqrt{2}q e^{-d^2/2q^2}H_{2k-1}(d/\sqrt{2}q)=q e^{-d^2/2q^2}He_{2k-1}(d/q)$$
Then from (1)
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}q}\sum ^∞_{k=1} \frac{(A^2/2q^2)^k}{2^k(k!^2)}\int^{-d}_{0} e^{−r^2/2q^2}He_{2k}(r/q)dr=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}q}\sum ^∞_{k=1} \frac{(A^2/2q^2)^k}{2^k(k!^2)}q e^{-d^2/2q^2}He_{2k-1}(d/q)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\sum ^∞_{k=1} \frac{(A^2/2q^2)^k}{2^k(k!^2)} e^{-d^2/2q^2}He_{2k-1}(d/q)$$

I have carried out calculation with the second integral of rhs of (1) and obtained the result. My question is whether the first integral of rhs produces a zero value? Please comment if any mistake is found.

Comment: Note that $\sum_{k=0}^\infty (x/2)^{2k}/k!^2=J_0(x)$, the Bessel function of order zero. This may help you get rid of the series.

Comment: good jesus...would u be so nice to replace $x/y$ by $\frac{x}{y}$? this would make everything much more readable

Comment: i would guess that u somehow have to use the representatin of Hermites polynomials in terms of derivatives of $e^{-x^2}$ which makes ipb a plausible route to go